# How can I send the value of a variable from one component to another? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components: `Card.js` and `Score.js`

I have a setScore in my Card.js component that increases by 1 every time I click a certain image.

`Card.js`

```
const Card = () => {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const incrementScore = () => {
    setScore(score + 1);
    if (score >= 8) {
      setScore(0);
    }
    console.log(score);
  };

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I need to gain access to that specific `Score` value inside my second component but I can't figure out how.

`Score.js`

```
const Score = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Score: ${score}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `props` :

```
// Card.js
return (
    <div>
        <Score score={score} />
    </div>
);

// Score.js
const Score = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Score: ${props.score}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the [doc](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. I'll read through the docs again but another question: I have a <p> tag in Score.js which shows the value of score on the screen. Because I have Score in two places now, I'm getting one value of undefined (on screen) and another of 0 (on screen) but I only have the value written in Score.js. How can I remove the undefined value without removing the other?

Comment: Why do you have score in 2 places ? In the example i gave in my answer, only one score should display. Do you mean in the console ?

Comment: I think because I'm running <Score /> in my Card.js it's doubling the output because the only thing I have in my Score.js component (so far) is the <p> tag. And in my Card.js file I have some images that I omitted. https://i.imgur.com/aY2GNoR.png Here's a screenshot

Comment: Cancel! I figured it out! I had it running in my index.js file as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the score value from the Card component to the Score component as a prop.

In the Card component, you can pass the score value as a prop to the Score component when you render it:

```
return (
    <div>
      <Score score={score} />
    </div>
  );
```

Then in the Score component, you can access the score prop using props.score and use it to render the score:

```
const Score = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Score: ${props.score}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You shall use [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Using props, you can pass data from one component to the other. In your case, you can pass the score value from your card component to the score component.

In your card component, you will pass the score value as a prop:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Score score={score} />
    </div>
);
```

Now in your Score component, you will render the score value using props.score:

```
const Score = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Score: ${props.score}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you want to pass props from parent to many children with complex structure. You can use "React Context" and also still have some other library for manage react state eg. Redux, Recoil, ...

Answer (score 1):

Import the score component in your card component and pass the prop from parent in your child component,Reactjs has a concept of props drilling

```
// Card.js
return (
    <div>
         //pass the prop from here
        <Score score={score} />
    </div>
);

// Score.js
const Score = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      //access the props
      <p>{`Score: ${props.score}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```